# Integral $\int \frac{1}{\left(x-2\right)^3\sqrt{3x^2-8x+5}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve the integral

$$\int \frac{1}{\left(x-2\right)^3\sqrt{3x^2-8x+5}}dx$$

I am pretty sure that a certain substitution should work.
I tried using $x-2=\frac{1}{t}$ and got
$$\int \:\frac{-\frac{dt}{t^2}}{\frac{1}{t^3}\sqrt{3\left(\frac{1}{t}+2\right)^2-8\left(\frac{1}{t}+2\right)^2+5}}$$

After some simplification:
$$\int \:\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{3\left(\frac{1}{t}+2\right)^2-8\left(\frac{1}{t}+2\right)^2+5}}$$

Any this point, I'm lost.

Comment: Multiply with the root quadratic so root is gone which is somewhat creting trouble i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point that you stopped:

> $$\int \:\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{3\left(\frac{1}{t}+2\right)^2-8\left(\frac{1}{t}+2\right)^2+5}}$$

$$=\int\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{5-5\left(\frac 1 t+2\right)^2}}=\int\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{-\frac{5}{t^2}-\frac{20}{t}-15}}=-\frac{i}{\sqrt 5}\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{3t^2+4t+1}}dt$$

$$\overset{\text{complete the square }}{=}-\frac{i}{\sqrt 5}\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt 3 t+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2-\frac 1 3}}dt$$

Set $u=\sqrt t+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$ and $du=\sqrt 3 dt$

$$=-\frac{i}{\sqrt 5}\int\frac{(2\sqrt 3-3u)^2}{27\sqrt{u^2-\frac 1 3}}du$$

substitute $u=\frac{\sec s}{\sqrt 3}$ and $du=\frac{\tan s \sec s}{\sqrt 3}ds$ then $\sqrt{u^2-\frac 1 3}=\sqrt{\frac{\sec^2 s}{3}-\frac 1 3}=\frac{\tan s}{\sqrt 3}$ and $s=\sec^{-1}(\sqrt 3 u)$

$$=-\frac{i}{81\sqrt 5}\int \sqrt 3 \sec s(2\sqrt 3-\sqrt 3\sec s)^2$$

$$=-\frac{i}{9\sqrt{15}}\int \sec^3 s ds+\frac{4i}{9\sqrt{15}}\int \sec^2 s ds-\frac{4i}{9\sqrt{15}}\int \sec s ds=\dots$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the shorthand $f(x)= \sqrt{3x^2-8x+5}$ to establish
$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac {6f(x)}{x-2}-\frac{f(x)}{(x-2)^2}\right)= \frac2{(x-2)^3 f(x)}-\frac9{(x-2)f (x)}
$$
and then integrate both sides to evaluate

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{(x-2)^3\sqrt{3x^2-8x+5}} dx\\
= & \ \frac {3f(x)}{x-2}-\frac {f(x)}{2(x-2)^2}
+\frac92\int \frac{1}{(x-2) f(x)}dx\\
=&\ \frac {(6x-13)\sqrt{3x^2-8x+5} }{2(x-2)^2}+\frac92 \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3x^2-8x+5}}{3-2x}
\end{align}
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4656680/686284) for evaluating the simpler integral $ \int \frac{1}{(x-2)f(x)}{dx}$ with $y=x-2$.